# How do I limit one pop up per user, using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Well I found this code for my blog:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
document.body.onclick= function(){ window.open('My site', 'poppage', 'toolbars=0, scrollbars=1, location=0, statusbars=0, menubars=0, resizable=1, width=950, height=650, left = 300, top = 50'); }
</script>
```

But since I know nothing about JS, I can't really edit it much.

Comment: On Chrome I can open only one popup. What browser are you targeting - or experiencing issues with?

Answer (score 2):

Check for a `localStorage` item before the popup displays, and when you display it, set the `localStorage` item. Since this won't work in the SO sandbox, here's a codepen https://codepen.io/mcoker/pen/PjqQqw

```js
document.body.onclick = function() {
  if (!localStorage.popup) {
    localStorage.popup = 1;
    window.open(
      "My site",
      "poppage",
      "toolbars=0, scrollbars=1, location=0, statusbars=0, menubars=0, resizable=1, width=950, height=650, left = 300, top = 50"
    );
  }
};
```

```css
body {
  min-height: 100vh;
}
```

Comment: OP asked also for jquery. I would recommend use .one function if you want to limit click once per page lifetime. On reload will be available again. http://api.jquery.com/one/

Comment: P.S: more readable and rememberable is to use: `!localStorage.popup` and `localStorage.popup = 1;`

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan I'm assuming OP means they only want the popup to display once for someone who sees the popup. By "user" they mean just someone who visits the site. Without additional details, that's what I'm assuming they mean. I'm doubting, for example, that they have a database of users or something where they have a flag that they check for before showing a popup, and set it once the popup is shown (similar to the logic in my answer).

Comment: @MichaelCoker yes... I think that too :)

Comment: @daremachine OP didn't ask for jquery. They said "using Javascript" and tagged JS and jquery in the post. And assuming this is to only show a popup once for a user, regardless the session or if they close the browser or whatever, `$.one()` is a completely different thing. That's just for a single click handler.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan neat! I didn't realize you could use `localStorage.itemname`, thanks!

Comment: Sorry I wanted only give more idea. I missed "session" part in question and I thought that tags are for section specification. My bad.

Answer (score 0):

```
document.body.onclick= function(){ window.open('My site', 'poppage', 'toolbars=0, scrollbars=1, location=0, statusbars=0, menubars=0, resizable=1, width=950, height=650, left = 300, top = 50');document.body.onclick=function(){} }
```

Reset the onclick attribute once it has been clicked once

Comment: smart **but**, on page refresh/history/navigate you'd get back the annoying popup, again.

Comment: Good point. You could create a cookie that stores whether or not the popup has occurred, and only show the popup if the cookie does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

Using cookies https://jsfiddle.net/arvinddhakad/bq8f241a/

```
document.body.onclick = function() {
    isPopup = document.cookie.replace(/(?:(?:^|.*;\s*)popup\s*\=\s*([^;]*).*$)|^.*$/, "$1") || false;
    if (!isPopup) {
        window.open('My site', 'poppage', 'toolbars=0, scrollbars=1, location=0, statusbars=0, menubars=0, resizable=1, width=950, height=650, left = 300, top = 50');
    document.cookie = "popup=true";
    }
}
```